# Image doesn't appear in leaflet overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

[tag:React js]Hi guys, I'm beginner in programming. I want to overlay drone's images on leaflet map but only my image's edges appear. How can i resolve.I'm using JavaScript with typescript (React js). Sorry for my English, i come from a french country. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex5rN.png).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.